# Does Ignite Spring Data supports Spring Boot 2?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ignite

I have trying to run `ignite-spring-data` with Spring Boot version `2.0.0-RELEASE` and getting the following error:

> Error:(35, 8) java: name clash: deleteAll(java.lang.Iterable) in org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository and
>   deleteAll(java.lang.Iterable) in
>   org.apache.ignite.springdata.repository.IgniteRepository have the same
>   erasure, yet neither overrides the other

Ignite Spring Data works fine with Spring Boot version `1.5.8-RELEASE`. When will it support Spring Boot 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Apache Ignite JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-6879), it should be supported in the next Ignite release, 2.7.

I think the support should also be in [nightly builds](https://ci.ignite.apache.org/viewLog.html?buildId=lastSuccessful&buildTypeId=Releases_NightlyRelease_RunApacheIgniteNightlyRelease&tab=artifacts&guest=1).

Comment: Thanks. It talks about Spring Data 2.0. Does that mean it would also support Spring Boot 2 in v 2.7?

Comment: @Lokesh Spring Boot 2.0 is already supported. Just the `ignite-spring-data` isn't.

Comment: Oh ok. Do you know where can I find nightly builds?

Comment: @Lokesh I've added a link to my answer